# R data.table: how do I make an OR statement in the i argument?

Tags: r, data.table

Here are two examples of what I am trying to achieve with OR statements:

**Example 1:**

```
DT = data.table("x" = letters[1:10], "y" = 1 : 10)
setkey(DT, x)
```

The rows corresponding to "d" and "g" are obtained via:

```
DT[J("d")]
   x y
1: d 4

DT[J("g")]
   x y
1: g 7
```

But how can I get perform an OR on the binary search and get both rows back?

```
   x y
1: d 4
2: g 7
```

**Example 2:**

```
DT2 = data.table("x1" = letters[1:10], "x2" = LETTERS[1:10], "y" = 1 : 10)
setkey(DT2, x1, x2)
```

I would now like to pull the rows corresponding either to x1 == "d" OR x2 == "G":

```
   x1 x2  y
1:  d  D  4
2:  g  G  7
```

Thanks!

Comment: Arun replied with the following solution to the first example:
DT[J(c("d", "g")), nomatch = 0L] but the answer appears to have been removed.

Comment: Thanks David! Does that solution make full use of the binary search? Is it much faster than `DT2[x1 == "d" | x2 == "G", ]` ?

Comment: Btw, I think @arun deleted his answer because you just added an additional question. This is not how things work here. If you have an additional question, post a new question. You can't expect one person checking every 5 mins if you added a new question and if his answer still valid

Comment: Actually i think your own solution will be the best one

Comment: Thanks, will run some test to compare speed. Apologies about the edited question, when I started editing nobody had replied yet so figured it was OK to do so.

Comment: `setkey` + a single binary search is almost always **slower** than the standard linear lookup - just smth to keep in mind while trying to speed up whatever problem you're solving

Comment: @eddi, right. Although what would be possible is to implicitly use fast-lookup by storing group indices as attribute - first search could still be slow, but subsequent lookups will be instant + reduces the need to set key or rearrange data, hence will be faster than the current setup even the first time.